# Updating the "title" attribute dynamically

Tags: jquery, attr

I am updating the "title" attribute of a div dynamically in a javascript function.  If I retrieve the new attribute, it's updated, but onscreen the old "title" still shows in the mouseover tooltip.  Is this a bug?  Is there a way around that?

```
    // Toggle and slide LinkCards
    if (toggle_class == 'ico_minim') {
        $(toggle).removeClass('ico_minim');
        $(toggle).addClass('ico_expand');
        $('#'+card_id).attr('title','Expand');
        alert(toggle_class+' '+$('#'+card_id).attr('title'));
        $('#'+card_id).css('height', min_height);
        slide_linkcards(card_id, height_adjust, toggle_class);
    }
    else {
        $(toggle).removeClass('ico_expand');
        $(toggle).addClass('ico_minim');
        alert('minimize'); 
        $('#'+card_id).attr('title','Minimize');
        alert(toggle_class+' '+$('#'+card_id).attr('title'));
        $('#'+card_id).css('height', exp_height);
        slide_linkcards(card_id, height_adjust, toggle_class);
    }
```

What can I change in the code to make the title show?

Comment: I don't think `div`s have a `title` attribute. Try using the `.data()` method if you want to store data in objects.

Comment: What browser are you on.  Works fine on Chrome.

Comment: @Blender Actually--in HTML5, anyway--[any element can have a title attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#global-attributes).

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: Hmm, didn't see that one yet. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Hmmm.  No clue.  +1 for the question though.  Good luck.

Comment: Allright. I'll look for an alternative.

Comment: Blame on IE :) Tried other browsers?

Comment: According to w3.org, `title` [is a valid attribute for divs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4).

Comment: I created a [jsFiddle.net test page](http://jsfiddle.net/hTDhG/1/) for this. It's quite simplified.

Comment: Doesn't in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hTDhG/2/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works.  Change title on $(toggle) instead of $('#'+card_id).

```
    // Toggle and slide LinkCards
    if (toggle_class == 'ico_minim') {
        $(toggle).removeClass('ico_minim');
        $(toggle).addClass('ico_expand');
        $(toggle).attr('title','Expand');
        /* alert(toggle_class+' '+$('#'+card_id).attr('title')); */
        $('.link_drop_box', $('#'+card_id)).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('#'+card_id).css('height', min_height);
        slide_linkcards(card_id, height_adjust, toggle_class);
        show_buttons(card_id, 'MINIMIZED');
    }
    else {
        $(toggle).removeClass('ico_expand');
        $(toggle).addClass('ico_minim');
        $(toggle).attr('title','Minimize');
        /* alert(toggle_class+' '+$('#'+card_id).attr('title')); */
        $('.link_drop_box', $('#'+card_id)).css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#'+card_id).css('height', exp_height);
        slide_linkcards(card_id, height_adjust, toggle_class);
        show_buttons(card_id, 'EXPANDED');
    }
```